# Error while running pjsip sample pjsua on android ndk

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, pjsip

I successfully performed `./configure-android` and make dep && make install commands using pjsip and I successfully install SWIG too.

But I am getting the following error while running the sample pjsua.

```
/Users/Downloads/swig-2.0.11 -c++ -o jni/pjsua_wrap.cpp -package org.pjsip.pjsua -outdir src/org/pjsip/pjsua -java jni/pjsua.i
make: execvp: /Users/Downloads/swig-2.0.11: Permission denied
make: *** [jni/pjsua_wrap.cpp] Error 127
```

Comment: Does swig-2.0.11 have executable permissions? 127, initially, is command not found error.

Comment: Ya..provided the executable permissions for the files in swig..

Comment: drwxrwxrwx@ 10 srikanth  staff      340 Sep 15 19:41 vms
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 srikanth  staff     2527 Sep 15 19:41 swig.spec.in
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 srikanth  staff      214 Sep 15 19:41 preinst-swig.in
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 srikanth  staff    74589 Sep 15 19:41 configure.ac
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 srikanth  staff      586 Sep 15 19:41 autogen.sh
drwxrwxrwx@  3 srikanth  staff      102 Sep 15 19:41 Win
drwxrwxrwx@ 13 srikanth  staff      442 Sep 15 19:41 Tools
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 srikanth  staff    13090 Sep 15 19:41 TODO
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 srikanth  staff    14079 Sep 15 19:41 RELEASENOTES

Comment: OK, I see what happens, in pjsua's Android.mk you set MY_SWIG to downloaded swig's folder but, this should point to swig binary file. In your case, this will be: /Users/Downloads/swig-2.0.11/swig

Comment: Can i contact you ...once can u pass on your email id ?

Comment: Can i have your email id ? i have some doubts regarding pjsip installation. want to talk to you once. Please pass on your email id or please send me test mail at srikraj8341@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry I missed this comment. Please, don't take it the wrong way but I would prefer to discuss this though chat or, maybe better, you can open a new question if you face new problems. By this way, we would be able to help other people facing same problems.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that MY_SWIG variable in `pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/android/Android.mk` is pointing to `/Users/Downloads/swig-2.0.11` instead to `swig` binary file.

If you downloaded `swig` source to `/Users/Downloads/swig-2.0.11` and you build it, binary file should be at: `/Users/Downloads/swig-2.0.11/swig`

Another problem you maybe find is that object files for project pjsua-app does not exists, this is because this is not done by default on the general build (more specifically, corresponding target is not included on `all` target at `pjsip-apps/build/Makefile`). To fix this just go to `pjsip-apps/build` and run:

```
make pjsua
```

This would create proper object files at: `pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/` (needed when building android sample)

Comment: Yes exactly...that was the problem and now i updated it. But now getting another error saying arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /Users/srikanth/trunk/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/pjsua_app.o: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /Users/srikanth/trunk/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/pjsua_app_cli.o: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /Users/srikanth/trunk/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libpjsua.so] Error 1

Comment: @srikayala Please, check my update for an explanation about the issue an how to fix it.